# Angular concatMap not calling next API

Tags: angular, concatmap

I am trying to make sequential http calls but the next function (i.e. `getGroups`) is not called.

These are my function signatures:

```
getTokenForGroups() : Observable<any>
getGroups() : Observable<any> // is not called
```

I've checked `getTokenForGroups` gets called, but my second function isn't.

```
let grps = []
this.getTokenForGroups().pipe(
    concatMap(tokenResult => {
      console.log(tokenResult);
      return this.getGroups(userId, tokenResult.token)
    }),
    tap(res => console.log("tap2, group result", res)),
  ).subscribe(groups => {
    grps = groups.value as string[];
    console.log(grps)
  }, error => {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Comment: is there any output from your console.log()'s ?

Comment: any of these, does not hit

Comment: put a catchError() inside your pipe() - and log that